# Populate from two collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have 2 Schemas defined for 2 different collections, and I need to populate one of them into the other:

stationmodel.js

```
var stationSchema = new Schema({ 
    StationName: 'string', 
    _id: 'number', 
    Tripcount: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tripcount'}]
},
    {collection: 'stations'}
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Station', stationSchema);
```

tripmodel.js

```
var tripSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: Number, ref: 'Station'},
    Tripcount: 'number'
},
    {collection: 'trips'}
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Tripcount', tripSchema);
```

According to the mongoose populate [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), this is the way to go. I have the problem that "Tripcount" remains as `[]` when I use Postman to GET the stations.

My DB Structure for the 'stations' collection:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "StationName": "Station A",
}
```

And for the 'trips' collection:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "Tripcount": 6
}
```

My routes.js:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/stations', function(req,res) {
        var query = Station.find().populate('Tripcount');
        query.exec(function(err, stations){
            if(err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(stations);
        });
    });

};
```

I can't seem to find the error, maybe someone here can spot a mistake I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are enclosing the mongoose [SchemaTypes](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) in single quotes, you either need to reference the [SchemaTypes](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) directly when you define a property in your documents which will be cast to its associated [SchemaType](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

For example, when you define the `Tripcount` in the `tripSchema` it should be cast to the `Number` SchemaType as

```
var tripSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    Tripcount: Number
}, {collection: 'trips'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tripcount', tripSchema);
```

and the station schema

```
var stationSchema = new Schema({ 
    _id: Number, 
    StationName: String, 
    Tripcount: [{ type: Number, ref: 'Tripcount'}]
}, {collection: 'stations'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Station', stationSchema);
```

Then in your `stations` collection, the documents would ideally have the structure

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "StationName": "Station A",
    "Tripcount": [1]
}
```

for the populate method to work, of which when applied as

```
Station.find().populate('Tripcount').exec(function(err, docs){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(docs);  
    // prints { "_id": 1, "StationName": "Station A",   "Tripcount": [{"_id": 1, Tripcount: 6 }] }
});
```

---

**Alternative Approach**

Another approach that you could take if the station collection does not have `Tripcount` field is to use the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operator found in the aggregation framework as:

```
Station.aggregate([
    { 
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "tripcollection",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "trips"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "StationName": 1,
            "trips": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$trips", 0] }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "StationName": 1,
            "Tripcount": "$trips.Tripcount"
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, docs){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(docs);  
    // prints [{ "_id": 1, "StationName": "Station A",  "Tripcount": 6 }] }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed everything according to your suggestion, however postman still shows `Tripcount:[]` for everything. I put my changed routes.js in my question.

Comment: I think it comes down to the "mongoose populate empty array" problem people having as well.

Comment: I have added an alternative that you could try, based on the premise that `stations` collection is related to the `trips` collection by the `_id` keys.

Comment: This is it, this is what I needed. As I don't have the tripcount field in the station collection, the other approaches don't work. This works perfectly. Thanks a lot!